# Run multiple jpynb files concurrently

Tags: python, jupyter

How could I write a jupyter notebook (python3) to run multiple other ipynb files at the same time?

The following codes are still running the these files sequentially.

%run notebook1.jpynb &
%run notebook2.jpynb &
%run notebook3.jpynb &

Comment: You can't just run them in parallel? With the jupyter notebook explorer for example %jupyter notebook and then open each of them

Comment: That is what i am currently do. But, I am looking for some quick solutions for that. I have more than 20 scripts, and some would run simultaneously, and some would run sequentially followed by the scripts run simultaneously. I am trying to link these scripts with one jupyter notebook to do that.